# Legend Entry Y-Shifted Along with Plot

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am using pgfplots for crystallographic data analysis. I can effectively use `yshift` to shift plots within the axis environment, however, the legend entry line reference also shifts. I originally intended to use pgfplotstable to simply add or subtract from every data point to shift but this was computationally intensive (many data points). Excuse the constant plot hack to have a drop-down plot. Representative Code (courtesy of commenter):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.13}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep = comma}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
20, 1000
70, 500
}{\data}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[black] table[x index = 0, y index = 1, col sep = comma] {\data};
\addlegendentry[]{040\_Mn}
\addplot[red!20!blue] table[x index = 0, y expr={\thisrowno{1} - 500}] {\data};
\addlegendentry[]{023\_Mn}
\addplot[yshift=-2cm,red!20!blue] table[x index = 0, y index=1] {\data};
\addlegendentry[]{035\_Mn}
\addplot[yshift = -5cm, red!30!blue] expression {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: It would be much more convenient if you could make an example that didn't rely on other files that are not available. So something like `\addplot[red!20!blue] table[x index = 0, y expr={\thisrowno{1} - 500}] {\twentythreeMn};` was very slow?

Comment: I tried to load the table first as a macro using `\pgfplotstable`, which in some cases went over memory. With this method it is approximately 1 minute per graph. Thank you! This works because I can do formatting using the key `each nth point` and then do a final run with all data points. In the future I thought of doing `xshift` and additional manipulation like `scale` treating the `addplot` as a layer within the `axis` environment. Can we separate the plot styling from its legend entry? Attempting to reciprocally shift the legend entry doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that you should remove the plots altogether, the code you have now doesn't show the problem at all, as there is no `yshift` anywhere. I mean either add the datafiles, or use some dummy data, e.g. as in https://bitbucket.org/snippets/torbjornt/ogExK

Comment: Very obvious, sorry, updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options. First, instead of `yshift`, use something like

```
\addplot[red!20!blue] table[x index = 0, y expr={\thisrowno{1} - 500}] {\data};
```

This subtracts 500 from the y-value in the table. You can use the name of a text file instead of loading into a macro (here `\data`) first.

Another option is to use `yshift`, but  add `forget plot` to the `\addplot` options. `forget plot` disables adding the plot to the legend, so you need `\addlegendimage{<style options for plot>}` instead.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.13}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
20, 1000
70, 500
}{\data}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[black] table[x index = 0, y index = 1] {\data};
\addlegendentry[]{040\_Mn}
\addplot[red!20!blue] table[x index = 0, y expr={\thisrowno{1} - 500}] {\data};
\addlegendentry[]{023\_Mn}
\addplot[yshift=-2cm,green,forget plot] table[x index = 0, y index=1] {\data};
\addlegendimage{green}
\addlegendentry{shifted}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]